# What is the limit of sin(|z|)/z as z approaches 0

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

The back of the book says the limit does not exist, would the reason be because it is indeterminate and you can't apply L'hospitals rule to the sin of the modulus?

Answer (score 2):

To prove that a limit doesn't exist, you can for example show that two partial limits gives different result. Here we have (if I note $z=x+iy$) $$\lim_{z\to 0, z \in \mathbb{R^+}}\frac{\sin|z|}{z} = \lim_{x\to 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^+}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}= 1$$ and $$\lim_{z\to 0, z \in \mathbb{iR^+}}\frac{\sin|z|}{z} =\lim_{y\to 0, y\in \mathbb{R}^+} \frac{\sin(y)}{iy}=-i.$$